# Audio recording with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: iphone, android, html

I'm trying to build a web application for iPhone and Android that deals with audio input.

Is this possible?

Comment: i surely recomend you to read this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently ... yes, or it should be able to when it's finished at least.  It will supposedly become possible using the device API which is due to be part of HTML5 when it's finished and released (HTML5 isn't finalised yet however, and information is subject to potential for change).

[W3C Device API Requirements (camera section)](http://www.w3.org/TR/dap-api-reqs/#camera)

[Sony Erricson community blog posting, with examples (pre-final API)](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers)

While it isn't explicitly mentioned in the W3C spec, audio recording as part of (web)camera interactions is, so it's definitely hopeful.  There seems to be a shortage of good information at this stage though.  I'd expect to see more as HTML5 comes closer to being finalised.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 **can not record audio** (at least currently). HTML basically is a markup language and therefore only declares how a browser should display certain content. Although HTML 5 introduces new features that make some interaction possible, you can't record audio straight into.. HTML (even saying that sounds wrong). When the HTML5 spec is finished, it might become reality, until then, no way.

Web applications that record audio normally require a plugin like Flash or Silverlight, because those can access system resources like audio hardware. Both are a no-go on iOS, although Flash is theoretically possible on Android, I don't know if it supports audio input.

I would suggest you write a native app (for iOS and Android) that can access the audio hardware and connects to your web application in the background, so that the recording takes place natively and the recorded audio will be transmitted to your servers (think of Shazam, for example).

Here are the basic developer guides on recording audio in:

- [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture)
- [OS X, iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1)

Comment: Could the person who downvoted my answer please explain **why**?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, HTML5 Can't record Audio. but in future, it will be able to, by using the Device's native features.

Answer (score 1):

A new MediaStream Recording API is being worked on. It is currently availble only in the Firefox Nightly build for demo purposes

Here's the draft with the latest updates directly form W3C site:
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/default/media-stream-capture/MediaRecorder.html

Also the following article covers up other attempts on recording audio and video directly in the browser:
http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording